# When asyncio transport.get_extra_info('peername') returns None?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio, python-sockets

Sometimes my asyncio transports return `None` instead of IP address and port:

```
address, port = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
```

[Here is what docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseTransport.get_extra_info):

> `'peername'`: the remote address to which the socket is connected, result of `socket.socket.getpeername()` (`None` on error)

However, nothing is said about the reasons causing the error. Should I try again? Should I close this connection immediately?

Comment: You might need to do a little digging to find the reason for the error to know what to do. If you get the underlying `socket` (I think you should be able to get it from `get_extra_info('socket')` You can call `socket.getpeername()` directly, and see what error it returns. FWIW, I believe this is delegates to the Linux socket's `getpeername` function, which does [document possible error causes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html)